# SQL range partitioning using arithmetical elements (addition) on usigned ints - will it optimise WHERE queries? (MySQL, PostgreSQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, optimization, partitioning, slice

I read about range partitioning in MySQL (and PostgreSQL) [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html). I am also aware, that if I partition my table, some WHERE queries will be optimised.

For example partitioning by used_at date:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (used_at) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-01-01'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-01'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01'),
);
```

Will make querting things like:

```
WHERE used_at >= '2013-05-01' AND used_at < '2013-09-01'
```

faster for example as it will only use a 1/3 size subtable practically for the search.

Well the question is if I have two tables:

```
user (3 000 000 records):
    user_id UNSIGNED INT ...
    ...


messages (50 000 000 records)
    sender UNSIGNED INT (refers to user)
    recipient UNSIGNED INT (refers to user)
```

We get threads like:

```
WHERE ... (sender = 1234567 OR recipient = 1234567)
...
GROUP BY (sender + recipient)
```

Well, my question is:

a) Am I able to partition by

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (sender + recipient) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2000000),
    ...
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (6000000),
);
```

?

b) If yes, will it optimise WHERE conditions like

```
WHERE ... (sender = 1234567 OR recipient = 1234567)
```

in case of unsigned ints?

The question is basically about MySQL but I am also curious about PostgreSQL and Oracle for the future.

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: I can only try it later as I need to seed up with data my local copy first (and before I will benchmark without partitions), but yeah, that would explain it all, I am just asking basically to get to know if it is worth caring.

So to make it clear, I do not even know yet if PARTITION BY RANGE (sender + recipient) is accepted at all.

Comment: MySQL's `PARTITION BY RANGE` accepts expressions & PostgreSQL's partitioning technique is based on `CHECK` constratints, which also accepts any (row-wise) expressions, so you *can* do it. However it isn't clear to me, **why** want you do it at all (partitioning on `sender + recipient`)? This is an arithmetic expression on primary keys (technically on foreign keys, which are primary keys on the referenced table). Also, it will only help you, if you are querying against `sender + recipient`, but not when `sender = ? OR recipient = ?`

Comment: " if you are querying against sender + recipient, but not when sender = ? OR recipient "
pozs this actually answered the question if it is true. So thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL...

```
WHERE ... (sender = 1234567 OR recipient = 1234567)
```

Does not optimize well.  it would be better to do

```
( SELECT ... WHERE sender = 1234567 )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... WHERE recipient = 1234567 )
```

and have *separate* indexes on sender and recipient (or at least starting with each).

PARTITION can handle a very few expressions, *not* including (x+y).

```
GROUP BY (sender + recipient)
```

cannot be optimized by any form of INDEX or PARTITION.  It will involve a full scan and probably a filesort.

If you meant `GROUP BY sender, recipient`, that's another matter.

```
WHERE used_at >= '2013-05-01' AND used_at < '2013-09-01'
```

Does *not* benefit from partitioning, at least no compared to having some INDEX starting with `used_at`.

```
WHERE used_at >= '2013-05-01' AND used_at < '2013-09-01'
    AND x = 1
```

Would like INDEX(x, used_at)

```
WHERE used_at >= '2013-05-01' AND used_at < '2013-09-01'
    AND x > 1
```

Is problematical -- two *ranges*.  In *this* example `BY RANGE` partitioning on either `x` *or* `used_at` would be beneficial.  This is because: first "partition pruning" would first pick the desired partition(s), then ordinary indexing (if any) would take over to finish the task.  (It is impossible to say what the optimal INDEX would be without further details on the table and the data distribution.)

I did not get your point on `users` plus `messages`.

Comment: Thanks, this is practically the correct answer for all the questions, but as it is an old post, it turned out since then, that in MySQL foreign keys and partitioning won't work together.

(I meant sender + recipient as sender plus recipient by the way, thanks for showing me it wouldn't work)